# How to get frequency of a phrase in a document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, phrase

I would like to get the frequency of a phrase (sequence of terms) in a specific document.

**Example:**

Consider the following documents, indexed by elasticsearch:

- *doc1: ONE TWO THREE ONE TWO*
- *doc2: THREE ONE TWO FOUR*

I want to issue a query, specifying a **phrase** and a **document** and gives me the phrase frequency in that document; e.g.:

`phrase_frequency(doc1, "ONE TWO") = 2`

`phrase_frequency(doc2, "ONE TWO") = 1`

I know that is has to be done with "span near queries", but could not find a way to get the frequency (instead of ranked list of documents).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) are the docs for span near queries in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks! But the quries presented there can only retrieve documents matching the phrase; i.e. I can get the number of hits, but not the number of time specific phrase appeared in a document